# How to programmatically refresh user defined form fields in Outlook mail

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am capturing data from Outlook mail with user defined form fields.

However certain form fields especially with validation is not showing correct values

e.g. timeline field has validation as Receivedtime + estimate though mostly it shows correct value sometimes timeline field does not show any values even if receivedtime field and estimate field has value in it.

If I open and close the mail manually the field refreshes and shows correct data. This makes me feel the fields are not updated automatically.

Is there any way to refresh the form field so that it can show updated data?

Comment: Your code wasn't working at all, besides the problem you mentioned.  I know because properly indenting the code identified that you have an `End If` with no `If`.  Please see [mcve].

Comment: Hi ashleedawg, thanks for the heads up I have made some changes to the question to make it more clear. I hav removed the code as it is not the main issue. I need the mail form fields to be updated programmatically.

Comment: I didn't mean you should remove should remove the code completely. (The problem *is* something in your code, correct?)  Is it important to include your code (and sample data when applicable), but my point was that it should be an "MCVE" code example (see "[mcve]").  But what you posted had other issues unrelated to your problem (a hanging `End If`.)  It's not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try

```
mailobject.userproperties.find("formfieldname").repaint
```

The repaint method will update the screen similar to refresh method. That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this question in another forum:
Link to the answer: [answer](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23889649/Outlook-MailItem-Custom-Fields-not-updating.html)

i.e

SendKeys "{F5}", True

This works for me